Topic not present error. Airbyte MongoDB source not syncing with Kafka destination
i have been able to setup my source as mongoDb, and Destination as Kafka on airbyte.
Connection works fine till its time for synchronization,
Challenge i am facing is the synchronization does not stop till it times out, while syncing i can see it fetching records from mongodb, but it keeps duplicating the records and give an error message
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot send message to Kafka. Error: Topic test_topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

For Context
I am running airbyte on my local machine
Kafka is running on a docker instance
test_topic exists on the kafka broker server, i have verified
Telneting to the bootstrap server works fine and shows that i am connected to the kafka server also
Been on this for 3 days, any help will be appreciated

Please show your Kafka connection configuration from airbyte and your docker run command or compose file
